# Discord bot won't come online after all code read and installed all dependancies

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a computer science project which focuses on a discord bot and followed the Tutorial at 'https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/' whoever after following the steps twice over my bot still wont come online, i don't see any problems;

```
{
“token”: “------------------------------- (correct token inserted)”
}

{
"name": "greeter-bot",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "My First Discord Bot",
"main": "bot.js",
"author": "Your Name",
"dependencies": {
  "discord.io": "https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6",
  "winston": "^3.1.0"
 }
}
```

with the bot code used in the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some problem."double quotes" is going wrong when you copy and paste the mark. So an invalid json file is occurring.

This is invalid.

```
{
“token”: “------------------------------- (correct token inserted)”
}
```

This is valid

```
{
    "token": "your-token"
}
```

Comment: I swapped the quotation marks but the bot remains offline

Comment: "type “node bot.js” in the Command Prompt (make sure you’re still navigated to your Discord bot folder)."